# StackOverflow Exception in OnetoMany Mapping JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am creating a mapping like:

[image: mapping1]

And i am using code:

**Payment entity**

```
@ManyToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinTable(
    name = "invoice_payment",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "pay_id" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "inv_id" ) }
)
private List<Invoice> invoices;
```

**Invoice entity**

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "invoices", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Payment> payment;
```

My problem is when i find payment entity detail using hibernate, I am getting StackOverflow Error.

I know this error occur because of Invoice in Payment and Payment in Invoice overflow chain.

I want same ER diagram.

[image: ErrorImage]

Comment: wonder what the stackoverflow exception is ...

Comment: Have you tried using @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference?

Comment: @BillyFrost Please check updated question.

Comment: @Thomas is this parsing issue?

Comment: why not just POST the stack trace IN THE QUESTION, rather than posting illegible images? Then we can see what part of the process is involved ... persistence, JSON, or what. "Cannot evaluate" .... but what cannot it evaluate ????